# How to show information through a drop down display?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying create a FQA page for my website. I would like for the user to be able to click on a question and the answer drops down and displays below. How can I do this? Can this be done with HTML?

Comment: With static HTML, no. With Javascript, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Jquery's slideUp , Slidedown** effects and on the click of a button or question (div) you can run that effect.

Check this link : [Jquery Slide effect](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp)